# Liferay's document library for multiple users with private repository/folder/files for each one

Tags: java, liferay, jackrabbit, document-library, jcr

I'd like to set up a portal where users don't cooperate but they are not aware of each other within the community. Each user works only with his files.

I don't see a way how to handle that via permissions non-programmatically.

Programmatically it may be possible to add a folder as a user, in which case that user would have the owner role for the folder and all descendant folders/files. And then set up document library actions only for owner role.

Another option for me is using Jackrabbit and OpenCMIS. I'd create multi-user repository and  then mount it to Liferay's Document Library. The Liferay login credentials would be Jackrabbit user credentials and I wouldn't have to deal with Liferay resource permissions.

Are there better ways ? Does these two have any flaws ? Your suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For document management per users I would use each individuals personal private community. This way they are allowed to do whatever they desire (create folders, permission them individually, add documents) and there wouldn't be any undesired affect on other users.

Is there a technical reason for not using these pages?

Comment: There would be double access to DL, either the user himself can do things and also another portlet is CRUD files in DL of particular users. If the DLFileEntry was created for that UserId, will permission system of private community work with this ? Afaik it'd work if the users were work with DL themselves, but if I add files programmatically, I'd have to play with resources for permission checking and that's very annoying thing to do.